# online qbsdk osr is broke. How to access it?

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

As of now I cannot reference the QBSDK OSR with either Firefox or MSIE 9.

How can I access it?

I have also installed QBSDK13 the other day which no longer supports QB Online.  Since there seems to be only 1 OSR on the system now I do not have access to QBO for our QBSDK12 and QBSDKD11 programs.

Another mess!!!!!!

Comment: Intuit broke this, and we already submitted a support ticket for it. StackOverflow is *not* an appropriate channel to report bugs to Intuit.

Comment: It is fixed. Can you please try this again.

Answer (score 0):

With SDK 13, QBO references were removed including in the OSR because you need to start using the QBO API. The above link will therefore not work.

Comment: The point is that we have many programs using QBFC12, 10, and earlier which are NOT going to moved to the QBO API at this time.  Now we have lost the ability to have adequate documentation (OSR) on either the local machine or the web.  

So moving to the QBO API is NOT a good answer.

Comment: It seems that once QBSDK13 is installed you always get the QBSDK13 OSR even if you move the version sider back to 12.  The QBO button never appears.

On another post that I made it also seems that at least on XP that even if you un-install QBSDK13 you still get the QBSDK13 OSR.  The QBSDK13 is not even removed from Program Files\..\IDN.  Even after renaming IDN\QBSDK13 you still get the 13 OSR from the GettingStarted.HTML in the QBSDK12 folder.

Just too difficult to know how to remove it.

It also appears that related issues for the DLLs (at least in Win 7).

Answer (score 0):

You are still welcome to use the older version of the SDK which has a local version of the OSR installed with it that does have the QBO information.

```
http://localhost:2211/Common/newOSR/index.html
```

You will not be able to access any data using QBXML on the newer versions of QBO.

Answer (score 0):

I have different versions of the SDK installed in different "virtual machines", so that I can always access the older SDK and OSR if necessary.